# Reference regarding Mobius Transformations.

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

I was looking for a complex analysis book which studies deeply Mobius Transformations. In both of the books Im studying, *Ahlfors, Complex Analysis* and *Conway, Functions on one complex variable* There is not enough information about them. Im looking for a book with examples, and maybe visual or geometric interpretations. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

T. Needham, *Visual Complex Analysis*.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the inexpensive [GEOMETRY](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486638308.html). Interest in German language publications in this area goes back, at least, to [Fricke and Klein (1897)](https://books.google.com/books?id=H5kLAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Vorlesungen%20%C3%BCber%20die%20Theorie%20der%20automorphen%20%20Functionen&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMIscb4rNvYxgIVSCiICh3qMwQX#v=onepage&q=muesli&f=false) which is very influential despite nobody being able to read it. I bought a paperback reprint. Very nice bit about indefinite ternary quadratic forms with integer coefficients, that are isotropic, pages 507-508.